# TF400813: The user 'myAdmin' is not authorized to access this resource. Error while creating TFS build Agent

Tags: tfs

While creating build Agent on my windows10 for the TFS(on premises) server getting an error -

TF400813: The user 'MyAdmin' is not authorized to access this resource.

Note - config.cmd running with Administrator.
       TFS server URL - http://tfs.mytfsservername.com/tfs/

Please help to resolve this ..

Comment: How did you deploy the build agent? Which authentication method do you use? PAT or normal username/password?

Comment: Normal Username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error message it should be the permission issue.

Please confirm if the user has the correct permission to register an agent. Please see [Confirm the user has permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts#confirm-the-user-has-permission) for details.

Comment: Yeah @Andy !This was a permission issue..Sorry for late replying.

Comment: I am having Admin access for Projects but not for AgentPools and this was the issue.